# Deployment of new version to containers

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, docker, ansible, go-cd

I'm running a CoreOS cluster on AWS.
On each instance in AWS I run a docker container.
For instance I have 2 instances named API which run a docker image with our latest software version.

I also have 6 proccessors instances that run another docker image with the latest version.

I want to update every container in my cluster so today I use [GoCD](https://www.go.cd) with pipeline to activate an ansible-playbook that does all the work.
The pipeline listens to github projects and once I push changes to that branch it activates the pipeline.

It builds the API and Processors new docker image,
It uploads the new updated image to dockerhub,
It then connects to the AWS instances and issue a docker pull for the image it just uploaded,
Eventually it starts the containers with the new pulled images.

This is the way I currently control my version deployment.

The issues are:

1. it takes long time
2. it sometimes fail for various reasons
3. it's not flexible (I need to hard code the specific branch to listen to on github and pull the files from)

Do you have any other suggestions \ tools to get this job done?
Sometimes I need to update 3 machines and sometime 7 and I need something that scales.

Comment: Did you ever give a look at fabric (fabfile.org)?

Comment: It's kind of like using ansible just different syntax..

Answer (score 1):

I do not use git in my environment but have used post-commit SVN hooks which kick off Jenkins deployment workflows. Add in the Jenkins [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) so you can resume from failures instead of restarting from the beginning. That said, check if GoCD supports this sort of thing, no sense in switching tools if it's not needed.

I would suggest the following changes:

1. Break the ansible playbook up into discrete steps in your deployment tool. This will allow you to restart closer to the failure, wasting less time.
2. Setup notifications in your pipeline to notify you of failures, and a single one at the end to notify you of success. There's no need to babysit a progress bar... that becomes frustrating quickly
3. Start quantifying where the bottleneck is in your process. You fix a slow process one step at a time, identifying the easiest things to fix first.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with issue #3, you might want to consider whether you want to release code from various branches. GoCD being a Continuous Delivery tool works best with trunk based development, i.e. always release from master.

You don't want to deploy to production directly on each push to trunk though. You can have a manual approval step in Go, or a set of automated tests being run with other components being the versions running in production, or both the tests and manual approval.

Regarding issue #2, you might want to have more steps in GoCD, so that you can follow the flow in the Go web UI, get email notifications on failures, and resume from the points where it failed etc.

Regarding #1, you have to tell us what's slow, and what kind of expectations you have on timing. GoCD isn't lightning fast in getting started with things. I think it polls the GIT repos once per minute, and the idle agents check in with the server at some interval to see if there is work to do. This is basically a fixed delay though. It won't get slower just because you have 100 hosts to upgrade, unless you make a GoCD job per instance (and that's probably not a good idea).

It sounds like docker compose and docker swarm might be better tools for the work you're using Ansible for.